# ArrayFormula boolean AND return a false positive

Tags: google-sheets, boolean, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to create a AND boolean comparison.

It gives me `same` when `different` is expected:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(K10:K, Q10:Q)*REGEXMATCH(L10:L, P10:P), "Same", "Different"))
```

as `A == A but B != ""`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(L10:L&K10:K=P10:P&Q10:Q, "Same", "Different"))
```

Comment: @EladBenda regexmatch throws error if there is no match found

Comment: Thanks, how can I check `L10` string contains `P10`?

Comment: @EladBenda it depends on dataset but most likely with regex check tho hard to tell if you dont share some sample spreadsheet with some example of dataset and the output you wish for. based on your initial question and provided screenshot the proposed answer should be more than enough